# Equivalent of html img src in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I am showing a link in an Android layout as follows:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/linkable_text”
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:autoLink="web"
                />
```

I also do: `text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

This works but I want to navigate to a different URL than the one displayed in my TextView (I add it dynamically).
I mean the link in the UI shows: `file.html` but when I press the link I would like to navigate to a url like: `http://IP/path/file.html`
How can I do that without having to show the whole URL in my TextView

Comment: You title is a little confusing.  Can you remove the *Img* part, as I am not it defines your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this, and let me know what happen..

TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

textView.setClickable(true);

textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Works! Is there a way to show the small hand that is displayed when a cursor goes over a link?